# Sorting in a list with fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have many .json files and one .xml in a zip. I want to sort the list when I do `fs.createReadStream` to view the XML file first.

What I do now

```
fs.createReadStream(savePathZip)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', function(entry) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this in a function that returns a Promise that is resolved when the stream 'close' event is emitted (as stated in the `unzip` docs), and in the promise resolution return a final list of files in the zip sorted by however you want to sort them. An example could be:

```
function getFileList(savePathZip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var list = []
    fs.createReadStream(savePathZip)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', entry => list.push(entry.path))
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('close', () => resolve(list))
  })
}
```

Then you can call the function, which returns a full list of files in an array and sort them however you like:

```
getFileList(zipFilePath).then(fileArray => {
  fileArray = fileArray.sort((f1, f2) => {
    /* sort the list of files however you like */ 
  })
})
```